# git: checkout files from another branch into current branch (don't switch HEAD to the other branch)

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I want to load a different version of the files that exist in another branch into my current branch.

`git help checkout` says:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or
   the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also
   update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.
```

Is there a way to checkout all those files, but *not* update HEAD?

Comment: @BobbyA I don't think so. 1: the question and answer are about something else (branch & file/folder name collisions). 2: this question is older.

Comment: I flagged the wrong question (multiple tabs), realized it immediately, and retracted the flag. I didn't realize there was a comment though. I got caught! Apologies :) Deleting that comment now since it's misleading

Answer (score 103, accepted):

checkout by providing the current path, `.`:

`git checkout other-branch-name -- .`

This operation is similar to [switching HEAD to another branch without checking out files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282639/switch-git-branch-without-files-checkout), but just from the "other direction".

As @김민준 mentions, this overwrites any uncommitted changes. Remember to either stash or commit them somewhere first if needed.

Comment: Just a heads up, this will discard all your uncommited work. Obvious in hindsight, but got bitten hard :'(

Comment: This is the easiest way to perform a merge from a feature branch from which you don't want to keep all the details. The `-- .` was a bit hard to find, thanks!

Comment: can you explain what -- . is actually doing? "." is here and -- with no argument mean "all" ?

Comment: As far as I know, Git uses `--` as a separator between the commands to the left and the file globs to the right.

Comment: This didn't work exactly for me, using Windows (maybe other differences?) I had to use `git checkout  <other-branch-name> -- C:\path\to\changes\*`

Answer (score 7):

Similar to [@Kache's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15536640/5532169), but using the newer [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) command (requires Git version 2.23 or above):

```sh
git restore --source=<other-branch/tag/commit> <pathspec>
# or
git restore -s <other-branch/tag/commit> <pathspec>

# example: to load all files from branch "other"
git restore -s other .
```

This new command was introduced to split "checking out a branch" and "checking out files" out of the single `git checkout` command. Read more: [What is the `git restore` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003030/5532169).

Comment: I would suggest adding the `--overlay` option to this command, otherwise you risk loosing everything that is not committed