# how to solve git not merging?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to merge a branch called development into my branch called component. I run the command git merge develop whiled having component checked out. I've done this several times before but now it isn't working. I get the message 'Already up to date' but the changes are not reflected on my branch. I tried this [git merge does not merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746325/git-merge-does-not-merge) with no results. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are you working with remote repo? Maybe it's stupid question, but... have you push it then?

Comment: Yes, the branch is already on my git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `git fetch` and trying again.
I believe the branch `component` may not be updated with the "remote" changes.

Comment: Well, it seems like none of the solutions above worked but thanks everyone. I had to delete the branch locally and on my git repo and created a new one. Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

are the changes in your development branch committed? 
use gitk command to check your repository, and post along your question to help us figure out what is going on.